Paste bullets and other symbols from Google Drive
I can copy a listed bullets from Word and detect all bullets in my code below:


document.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const preview = document.querySelector('.preview');
  const text = await navigator.clipboard.readText();
  console.log(text);
  preview.innerHTML = text;
});
<button class="btn">Click me</button>

<h1 class="preview"></h1>



But when I copy a set of list items with bullets from Google Drive my code ignores all of the bullets
How can I get the bullets of Google Drive in console.log(text)?
Note: If you copy the list from Google Drive to Word, then there are bullets in the pasted text into the word. So there are bullets metadata in the copied text but our code cannot detect them.
Copied from Microsoft word:

Copied from Google Drive:


Try assigning innerhtml with backticks in js. You can also try rendering text inside pre inside html.

No difference......

Use read instead of readText. Then you can get the blob and convert that to a document. Last, use the body of that document for the list:


const blobToHTML = (blob, target) => {
  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = (event) => {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const doc = parser.parseFromString(event.target.result, 'text/html');
    console.log(doc);
    target.innerHTML = doc.body.innerHTML;
  };
  reader.readAsText(blob);
};

document.querySelector(".btn").addEventListener('click', async() => {
  try {
    const clipboardContents = await navigator.clipboard.read();
    for (const item of clipboardContents) {
      if (item.types.includes("text/html")) {
        const blob = await item.getType("text/html");
        blobToHTML(blob, document.querySelector(".preview"));
      }
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
  }
});
<button class="btn">Click me</button>
<p class="preview"></p>



Not sure if this is the best way, but it works.
